# c:import jsp page with translation

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm trying to load a jsp from remote during runtime. <c:import> accepts remote url and loads the file but it displays the jsp content as it is. Downloaded jsp has custom tags in it which needs to be processed. Library of Tag handlers for the custom tags is added as dependency.

Is there a way to achieve html translation for imported jsp file?

Comment: Have you tried using `<jsp:include>` instead?